# Want to call a PHP page when a div is clicked?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html

I want to call a PHP page when the user is clicked on a `<DIV>` using AJAX. At the same time I want to change the Text of the DIV as LOADING.....

I don't know much about AJAX, so please give me details about that also.....

Thanks in advance......

Comment: Well if you don't know much about the subject i'd recommend using some javascript library like jquery. For examples you can check the documentation here http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: look on this example http://www.electrictoolbox.com/load-content-jquery-ajax-loading-image/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jquery you can do

```
$("div#id").click(function(){
 $(this).text("Loading...").load("/path/to/file.php");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div onclick="send_ajax_request(); document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'block';"> 
  <div style="display: none" id="loading">Loading ...</div>
</div>
```

send_ajax_request() is your function to call the ajax request. the 2nd statement will make the inner div visable (style="display: none" will make it invisible by default).

Answer (score 0):

Do something like.

```
< div class="loader" id="ajaxloaddiv">Initial data</div>
```

In ajax function use :

```
$('#ajaxloaddiv').click( function() {
    $(this).text("Loading...");
    ...
    ... do processing here
    ...
    return false;
});
```